# Downloadable Fonts Exception

Tags: android, android-resources, android-fonts

I decided to use [Downloadable fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) in my project. I implemented everything as recommened in the guide.

The following problem occured, when i tried to get font from **ResourcesCompat** next way:

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.roboto_bold)
```

After that, i always get this exeption:

```
Font resource ID #0x7f090005 could not be retrieved
```

How to solve this problem?

PS:

1. support-compat library v27
2. min sdk 16
3. solution via **ResourcesCompat.FontCallback** is not a good way in my case
4. problem occurs on devices with and without **Google Play Services**

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825038/font-resource-could-not-be-retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html#via-android-studio:

> You can set your application to download fonts by using Android Studio
>   3.0. To help you get started with the Downloadable Fonts features, you can use the font provider from Google Play services.
>
> **Note: A device must have Google Play services version 11 or higher to use the Google Fonts provider.**